# Wordpress country selection

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following website: www.example.com

I would like for this to only have a holding page requesting the user to select a country out of a choice of two: United Kingdom and France.

Upon selection, I would like the user redirected to either uk.example.com or fr.example.com - and I would like this choice remembered (i.e if the user was to enter www.example.com again, they should automatically go to fr.example.com).

How is this most easily achieved?

Comment: Two hrefs? 1) `href="fr.example.com"` . 2) `href="uk.example.com"` . After that you could save in cookies the user's selection. Everytime he lands on this page you first check if the cookie holds any data. If yes read that data and redirect otherwise let him choose. If cookie is empty then you could just set the selection in the page that he will land. For example, when user chooses 'uk', check in that page if cookie is null, if it is store it with "uk" - same happens with fr. Consider trying that first, and if you have a problem post `code block` and the specific problem. :)

Comment: Also, you could search if a plugin already exists with this functionality which i am pretty sure that you will find something (personally i don't know)

Answer (score 0):

For this wordpress have a plugin [Contry IP Specific Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/country-ip-specific-redirections/). Please check it once.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by using Wordpress Multisite and I2PLocation Redirection.